# Hostmonster Java Support

Tags: java, hostmonster

I have a hostmonster account.

How do I figure out if it supports Java ?

If no how can I install Java on it ?

Comment: I don't this is really programming related. And it would probably be faster to ask their customer support.

Answer (score 1):

You have a remote shell access (ssh), so simply connect to hostmonster and type `java -version`.

OTH - if I look at the [feature list](http://www.hostmonster.com/hosting_features.html), I see that they offer a lot of script language support but I see not indication for Java.